# SQL Server is not found or accessible from IIS

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, iis, .net-core

I have deployed my `.NET 5.0` app on `IIS`, which is a basic `API` and has `context and controllers`. Context has a defined configuration, which has connection string:

```
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=localhost;Database=flutter;");
        optionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
    }
```

Everything works fine when am hosting my app locally and requests are doing just fine but as soon as I try to call an `API` on my server, it's failing.

**Calling a default `API` call returns `200 OK`**
[image]
**but as soon as I call an endpoint which gets data from database, I get `500`**
[image]

**As I've checked `Event Viewer` after calls, I've found an error:**

``` Category: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpServer EventId: 2 SpanId: 73e6b4810067764d TraceId: 2c38235f0fa745438ce6ecdcf1874c44 ParentId: 0000000000000000 RequestId: 80000072-0001-fe00-b63f-84710c7967bb RequestPath: /FlutterAPI/api/Users/5 Connection ID "18302628891539275888", Request ID "80000072-0001-fe00-b63f-84710c7967bb": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application. Exception: Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SNI_PN11, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (87): The parameter is incorrect. at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action``1 wrapCloseInAction) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover, SqlAuthenticationMethod authType) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, String accessToken, DbConnectionPool pool) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.WaitForPendingOpen() --- End of stack trace from previous location --- at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean errorsExpected) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable``1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(DbContext _, Boolean result, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func``4 operation, Func``4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable``1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync() at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.SingleOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable``1 asyncEnumerable, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.SingleOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable``1 asyncEnumerable, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at FlutterApi.Controllers.UsersController.GetUser(Int64 id) in G:\Projects\flutter_api\ApiFlutter\Controllers\UsersController.cs:line 39 at lambda_method6(Closure , Object ) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask``1 actionResultValueTask) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Extensions.UsePathBaseMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContextOfT``1.ProcessRequestAsync() ClientConnectionId:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 Error Number:87,State:0,Class:20 ```

**My SQL Server is up and running**

[image]

**I have added required users (to my mind) to database's logins**
[image]

**My IIS setup looks like this:**
[image]

**And my application pool settings look like this**
[image]

For the past few days I've been searching through web and trying different things to solve this, but I just can't. I have tried different setups on IIS, different approaches, different servers but can't make it work. Desperate for help. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT 1:**
Updated SQL Server to the latest CU version

Comment: FYI, I really suggest updating your instance; your about 3 years behind as you're running the RTM release.

Comment: @Larnu instance of what?

Comment: Your SQL Server Instance. It's 2019 RTM.

Comment: Is TCP/IP enabled in SQL Server Configuration Manager for the instance?  For Developer and Express Edition it's disabled by default.

Comment: Isn't it the latest version as far as I can see?

Comment: I have enabled TCP/IP and added an Inbound rule in firewall

Comment: @KęstutisRamulionis, see [Solving Connectivity errors to SQL Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/sbs/topic/solving-connectivity-errors-to-sql-server-ae23c94b-b64b-5056-8b62-22e1694bb889?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Comment: No, @KęstutisRamulionis , again, yours is 3 years of unapplied updates. The latest is CU11, 15.0.4138.2, or if youre against CUs then the latest GDR build is 15.0.2080.9.

Answer (score 1):

you have a problem with connecton  string.  You can use integrated security without password

```
optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Data Source=localhost;Initial catalog=flutter;Persist Security Info=True;Integrated Security=SSPI;");
```

or add a  user account  with password to SQL server  security and use this

```
@"Data Source=localhost;Initial catalog=flutter;Integrated Security=False;User ID=..;Password=...;"
```

this variant is much more flexible since you can define a set  of  all needed permissions.

And since you are working witn net core you have to add a special pool for your web api. Call it FlatterApi for example. In Advanced settings changed "Net Clr Version" to "No Managed Code", "Identity" to "App Ppool Idenity"
Select this pool as an app pool for your webapplication.

Using sql management studio add to  Flatter db security new account (without login) and type IIS APPPOOL\FlatterApi as account name and select all permission for this db

Comment: Tried both ways, did not work, same error persists.

Comment: @KęstutisRamulionis Check my updated  answer

Comment: I was not able to create that profile, apparently it just does not let me and says that it does not exist

Answer (score 0):

You should open Sql configuration setting (search for it), then allow TCP connection.
To test yourself, create an empty text file, change the extension to .udl, double click it, configure the connection, save, then open the file with a text editor to see the right connection string.

Comment: I got almost the same string and without a Server.. Still doesn't work at the moment

Comment: Are you able to establish connection with the UDL file?

Answer (score 0):

So I have managed to deal with the problem, but not really sure which solution actually solved it since I kind of messed up publishing the app so some changes didn't go into IIS and finally all of them were published. Firstly I'll just leave my connection string for anyone that have problems in future:

```
Server=DESKTOP-******;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=yourDB;
```

Then I just migrated my connection string to appsettings.json (not sure if this one had any impact)
Then on my DefaultAppPool I selected ApplicationPoolIdentity as Identity and had an error that I didn't have permissions to SELECT from table so I added a user `IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool` to my SQL Server -> Security -> Logins and apparently it worked. Also started all of SQL Server Services (Server, Server Browser, Server Agent). Not sure if missed any other steps but hope it helps. Thanks everyone

Comment: Almost certainly it was the last step of starting services that did it, as you were not getting login errors, only connection errors